# Printing file systems in ansible_mounts

Tags: ansible

I am trying to iterate over ansible_mounts variable and print the mount points that are gathered during fact checking. Based on the documentation I would have expected the following to work:

```
- debug: msg={{item.mount}}   
  with_items: ansible_mounts
```

When I run the playbook with fact gathering enabled I get a number of errors. What is the correct way to print all of the file systems accessible to a host? It looks like ansible_mounts is a list of dictionaries so maybe I need to adjust my syntax? I'm currently running ansible 2.2.

Comment: Yes, bare variables are not supported in `with_...` since 2.2

Answer (score 9):

This tasks shows the info you want:

```
- debug: msg="{{ item.mount }}"
  with_items:
  - "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
```

or

```
- debug: var=item.mount
  with_items:
  - "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
```